# Bug in the search engine — Why does the search engine fail to find the page?

Tags: bug, search

There is a bug in your search engine. I was looking for the page [*ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33966/name-or-data-on-this-error-alert-phenomenon*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33966/name-or-data-on-this-error-alert-phenomenon).

With the words “name alert”, it was not found. Neither with the words “name alert phenomenon”.

Thank you for fixing that, and keep up the good work !

Nicolas

Comment: I went and echoed this bug [on the main post about the new search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange/168240#168240)